# Error 401 in windows command prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, host, http-status-code-401

When use npm run dev, which scripts the "node app.js" to run. But when I try to run it, I get this error code:

```
C:\Users\rfasc\Dropbox\Hackathon\HackCuTwitter>npm run dev

> Tweeter@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\rfasc\Dropbox\Hackathon\HackCuTwitter
> node app.js

Error: Status Code: 401
    at Request.<anonymous (C:\Users\rfasc\Dropbox\Hackathon\HackCuTwitter\node_modules\twitter\lib\twitte
 r.js:274:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\rfasc\Dropbox\Hackathon\HackCuTwitter\node_modules\request\request.js:
 1074:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] 
(_http_client.js:473:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:362:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

I also get this error when I try to run sudo at all when I use bash in the cmd:

```
ryryfasch@LAPTOP-9TPB1OJ6:/mnt/c/Users/rfasc/Dropbox/Hackathon/HackCuTwitter$ sudo i
sudo: unable to resolve host LAPTOP-9TPB1OJ6
```

I have tried looking up many fixes and can't figure it out. Thanks.

Here is my app.js file:

```
var twitterpack = require('twitter');

var tokens = {
  consumer_key: '----------SaaqAe9yVvr30CF',
  consumer_secret: '---------------oK7Dfj3zoiZ2nUOTBWUjP4DqtGXIlzzbxbOY',
  token_key: '  -----------------3N6RZJeOtJeH8ZhrursJUQlAqCycHqxbl',
  token_secret: '---------------2QYwSSZStETF7Mr2mBikHYCTTqodV'
}
var Twitter = new twitterpack(tokens);

Twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'hey'}, function(stream) {

  stream.on('data', function(stream){
    console.log(tweet.text);
    var meanReply = {status: "hey @" + tweet.user.screen_name}
    Twitter.post('statuses/update', meanReply, function(error, tweetReply, response){
      if(error) {console.log(error) /*&&db.collection('errors', error.text)*/};
        console.log(tweetReply.text)}
    );
  });
  stream.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: HTTP 401 - Means you're unauthorised. You most likely will need to authenticate against the service you're attempting to hit.

Comment: How would I go about figuring that out? @RobertSeaman

Comment: Well, I can only guess by the name of your script that you're attempting to connect to Twitter. In `app.js` do you attempt to authenticate against Twitter, or perform any actions that might require authentication?

Comment: Yes, but this has happened anytime I use `sudo` too, not just involving app.js. @RobertSeaman

Comment: I'm confused by your `sudo` command. Is this on Windows 10? And are you trying to run `sudo i`? This would be very hard to diagnose without providing snippets of your code from `app.js`.

Comment: I am in windows but am running a bash script on cmd prompt and whenever I use `sudo` it gives the error. I will post the app.js entirely. @RobertSeaman

Comment: What do you mean? @RobertSeaman

Comment: Oh yeah thank you. @RobertSeaman

Comment: I tried running sudo with anything, I was just giving an example there @RobertSeaman